# How was Kerrigan able to read data in "The Moebius Factor" but not "With Friends Like These..."?

Tags: starcraft-2

In [The Moebius Factor](https://starcraft.fandom.com/wiki/The_Moebius_Factor), Commander Raynor chases Kerrigan around Tyrador VIII destroying data cores before Kerrigan can access them. In the prologue to [With Friends List These...](https://starcraft.fandom.com/wiki/With_Friends_Like_These...), Kerrigan has a discussion with Abathur on why the Zerg couldn't access the Terran network, and Abathur said that it was because the Zerg are too complex to understand Terran communications.

Why then, was the old Queen of Blades able to access (presumably encrypted) data from the Moebius Foundation, but the new queen of blades was not able to access information from a terran network?

Comment: Your link to 'With Friends Like These' doesn't mention the conversation between Kerrigan and Abathur; I am unable to find any evidence of such a transcription elsewhere. Can you provide reference?

Comment: @onewho I am playing HotS campaign right now. Abathur doesn't say that as part of mission dialog, it is one of the conversations you can have in the evolution chamber between missions. I'm not going to look for a transcript because I don't want to spoil things for myself, but if you can find a list of those conversations you'll find it in there.

Comment: @Cody I'll dig for it. I don't think there is a solid answer to this (at-least nothing from Blizzard), but I have a theory.

Comment: @Cody I added a YouTube link with a specific timestamp, so it shouldn't spoil anything. He specifically says Zerg are incompatible with Terran machinery. I respect not wanting to spoil anything for yourself. I'm working on Legacy of the Void myself right now.

Comment: @onewho What's your theory?